# Customizing enumerate bullets in .sty

Tags: lists, packages, enumerate

The default enumeration style with the `enumerate` package is as follows:

```
1. First item
    a) first item, first thing
    b) first item, second thing
2. Second item
    a) second item, first thing
```

I wish to alter this slightly over multiple documents. Is it possible to specify enumeration styles for a nested list within a .sty file? I want every file that uses `style.sty` to have lists that look like this:

```
1. First item
    i) first item, first thing
    ii) first item, second thing
2. Second item
    i) second item, first thing
```

Comment: Must the second level labels be left aligned?

Comment: no, I just want lower-case roman numerals.

Comment: It's easy then: `\renewcommand\labelenumii{\roman{enumii})}` in your preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the OP uses `enumerate` package way I wanted to show an `enumitem` solution, applying the easy to use `\setlist` command.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\roman*)}   % Setting the 2nd level list to use lower case roman `numbers` as label
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First subenum
  \item Second subenum
  \end{enumerate}
\item Second
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First subenum
  \item Second subenum
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]